# How do I create a Gradient Background in Vulkan?

Tags: background, gradient, vulkan

I have been tinkering with the Vulkan Triangle demo.  I am trying to get a gradient background instead of a solid color.  In OpenGL this is easily done by rendering a quad and keeping background pixels.  When I do this in Vulkan, the quad covers up the triangle.  Anyone have an idea how to do this?  I tried separate render passes but don't know how to keep the pixels from the first renderpass (background) Any help or sample code would be appreciated.  Thanks,

Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got the depth buffer clearing working correctly.  Here is the code snippet.  Put this command inbetween the render of the background and the triangle.

```
    VkClearDepthStencilValue val;
        val.depth = 1.0f;
        val.stencil = 0;
        VkImageSubresourceRange range;
        range.layerCount = 1;
        range.levelCount = 1;
        range.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_DEPTH_BIT;
        range.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        range.baseMipLevel = 0;
        vkCmdClearDepthStencilImage(m_drawCmdBuffers[i], m_depthStencil.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, &val, 1, &range);
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no need for separate passes, you can render the gradient quad as is before the hello triangle.

If you have a separate shader for it, then you can bind it then. If the data is in a separate VBO then you bind it as needed.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a separate render pass if you just want a full screen quad to display a gradient. Actually it's pretty much the same as you'd do in OpenGL. Render a triangle or quad that covers the whole screen with the gradient, and then draw the triangle. If your quad is hiding the triangle even though the triangle is closer to the viewer (on the z-axis), you may have depth testing disabled.

Comment: How do I clear the depth buffer manually in Vulkan, without clearing the color buffer.  In OpenGL it was glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

Comment: [vkCmdClearDepthStencilImage](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/vkCmdClearDepthStencilImage.html) can be used for that. Note that this requires the TRANSFER_DST to be set for your depth/stencil image used as the attachment at that you need to transfer it to the proper layout before calling that command.

Comment: VkClearDepthStencilValue val;
   val.depth = 0.0f;
   val.stencil = 1;
   VkImageSubresourceRange range;

   vkCmdClearDepthStencilImage(m_drawCmdBuffers[i],m_depthStencil.image, VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_GENERAL, &val,1, &range);

Comment: The above code is not making any difference.  Could you help me with the settings? Thanks.  I can email you my project if you want.